# Adding query Parameters to Go Json Rest

Tags: json, rest, go, query-string, json-api

I am using the library go-json-rest.  I'm trying to recognize queries parameters in the code for example localhost:8080/reminders?hello=world I want to access {hello: world} .  I have the following code:

```
//in another function
&rest.Route{"GET", "/reminders", i.GetAllReminders},

func (i *Impl) GetAllReminders(w rest.ResponseWriter, r *rest.Request) {
    reminders := []Reminder{}
    i.DB.Find(&reminders)
    w.WriteJson(&reminders)
}
```

I know that r.PathParams holds the url parameters but I cannot seem to find how to the query parameters past the "?" in the url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that go-json-rest is a thin wrapper on top of `net/http`, have you looked at [that package's documentation](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/)? Specifically, [the Request object](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request) has a field `Form` that contains a parsed map of query string values as well as `POST` data, that you can access as a `url.Values` (`map[string][]string`), or retrieve one in particular from `FormValue`.

Comment: Yea I found it a few hours later.  It was stashed in that parameter.  r.URL.Query().  I'm pretty new and I had a hard time recognizing the interface in the source code.  Thanks.